# Poker how many ways to make 4 of a kind

Tags: combinatorics, games

In this [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Poker.html) it say there 13 X 48 = 624 ways to make 4 of a kind from card deck
Where does the 48 come from?
I can get 4! = 24 but I cannot get the 48

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 48 refers to the fifth card, it's a five-hand poker right? Any other card will do after the four. Perhaps you will find the following product less confusing

$$\binom{13}{1} \binom{4}{4} \binom{48}{1}$$

where we choose the card in 13 ways, choose the four of a kind in 1 way and the fifth card in 48 ways.